How to pass input parameters through RunnableSequences in LangChain v0.2?
I am struggeling with basic chaining and passing input parameters through RunnableSequences in LangChain v0.2.
I have two chains: code_chain and test_chain.


Now I want to chain them together.

This is my current code:
code_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("Write a very short {language} function that will {task}");
code_chain = code_prompt | llm | {"code": StrOutputParser()};

test_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("Write a test for the following {language} code:\n{code}");
test_chain = test_prompt | llm | {"test": StrOutputParser()};

chain = code_chain | test_chain;

result = chain.invoke({
    "language": "python",
    "task": "reverse a string",
});

Because code_chain does not retain the language parameter as an output, it is missing in the test_chain:
KeyError: "Input to PromptTemplate is missing variables {'language'}.  Expected: ['code', 'language'] Received: ['code']"
How do I pass the language input of the first chain to the language input of the second?

It turns out my question is a duplicate of How to include the inputs of the first chain to the second chain in LangChain's SequentialChain?.
To fully control the flow of variables through the pipeline we can use RunnableParallel objects:
chain = RunnableParallel({
    "language": RunnablePick("language"),
    "code": code_chain | RunnablePick("code"),
}) | RunnableParallel({
    "language": RunnablePick("language"),
    "code": RunnablePick("code"),
    "test": test_chain | RunnablePick("test"),
});

Now we have all variables available in our output: language, code, and test.

And what if we need to "share" some input across sequential chain, are there any reciepes? Or I need to pass through it every pipeline "element"?

in LCEL syntax
code_chain = code_prompt | llm | {"code": StrOutputParser()};

this part {"code": StrOutputParser()} defines the output key. code_prompt defines the input variables. chain is a pipeline, you are passing input variables to the prompt template, getting the result from open ai server as dictionary with output keys. then those output keys are passed to the second chain as input variables. your second chain expects those input variables: language and code
test_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("Write a test for the following {language} code:\n{code}");

but output keys for the first chain is only code, so you have to add language output key here:
code_chain = code_prompt | llm | {"code": StrOutputParser(),"language": StrOutputParser()};


That does not work, because the output of llm is only a string.
If I change the code like that:
code_chain = code_prompt | llm | {"code": StrOutputParser(), "language": StrOutputParser()};
The output of the code_chain is
{'code': '\n\ndef add(x, y):\n    return x + y', 'language': '\n\ndef add(x, y):\n    return x + y'}
